# C++ Event handler with derived classes through a base class array

Tags: c++, class, event-handling, derived-class, overloading

I have been trying to make a game engine for some time, and for the most part it has been turning out quite well, considering it's the first one i've made. But when I started to make an event send/recieve system with derived classes contained in a base class pointer vector array, I had some trouble making the reciever get the class type and use the proper function; here's what I have:

This is my base class Object:

object.h:

```
#include "all.h" //Contains '#include "SDL/SDL.h"' and constant variables.
#include <vector>
#include "mask.h" //An unimportant class used for collision checking
class Body;
class Room;
class Object//Objects that belong here are those without step events.
{
public:
    vector<vector<Room> > *world_map;//Should hold the address of the world map.
    Room *room;//The room holding this object.
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
    unsigned int pos;//Position of the object in the room's list.
    int depth;//The deeper it is, the later it will be drawn.
    virtual void draw(SDL_Surface *buffer,int viewx, int viewy){}
    virtual void interact(Body *body);//Sends a pointer of this object to the
                                      //the obj_event function of the body calling it.
    Object(unsigned int xx=0, unsigned int yy=0,int d=0):x(xx),y(yy),depth(d){}
};

#endif // INSTANCE_H_INCLUDED
```

object.cpp:

```
#include "object.h"
#include "body.h"

void Object::interact(Body *body)
{
    body->obj_event(this);
}
```

This is my derived class Body:

body.h:

```
#ifndef BODY_H_INCLUDED
#define BODY_H_INCLUDED

#include "all.h"
#include "object.h"
class Entity;
class Enemy;
class Player;
class Body : public Object//Objects that belong here are those with step events.
{
public:
    int priority;//Decides which body will perform their step event first.
    virtual void step()=0;
    Body(int xx=0, int yy=0, int d=0, int p=0):Object(xx,yy,d),priority(p){}

    //These scripts are for handling objects and bodies it has called through
    //interact()
    virtual void obj_event(Object *object){}
        virtual void obj_event(Entity *entity){}
            virtual void obj_event(Enemy *enemy){}
            virtual void obj_event(Player *player){}
};

#endif // BODY_H_INCLUDED
```

there is no body.cpp

This is my derived class of Body, Entity:

entity.h:

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H_INCLUDED
#define ENTITY_H_INCLUDED
#include "all.h"
#include "body.h"
#include "items.h"
#include <vector>
#include "mask.h"

class Entity : public Body
{
public:
    vector<Item> inv;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    Mask mask;
    Entity(int xx,int yy,int w,int h,int d=0,int p=0);
    void step();

    void collide_action(Entity *entity);
    virtual void obj_event(Player *player);
    virtual void obj_event(Enemy *enemy);
};

#endif // ENTITY_H_INCLUDED
```

entity.cpp:

```
#include "entity.h"
#include "room.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "enemy.h"

Entity::Entity(int xx,int yy,int w,int h,int d,int p):Body(xx,yy,d,p),width(w),height(h),mask(xx,yy,w,h,m_rectangle)
{}

void Entity::step()
{
    for(int iii=0;iii<room->inv.size();iii++)//Iterates through objects
    {
        room->inv[iii]->interact(this);
        mask.update(x,y,width,height);
    }
    for(int iii=0;iii<room->index.size();iii++)//Iterates through bodies
    {
        room->index[iii]->interact(this);
        mask.update(x,y,width,height);
    }
}

void Entity::collide_action(Entity *entity)
{
    if(entity!=this)
    {
        if (mask_collide(mask,entity->mask))
        {
            short xchange;
            short ychange;
            if (entity->x<x)
            {
                xchange=width-(x-entity->x);
            }
            else
            {
                xchange=(entity->x-x)-width;
            }
            if (entity->y<y)
            {
                ychange=height-(y-entity->y);
            }
            else
            {
                ychange=(entity->y-y)-height;
            }
            if(abs(xchange)<abs(ychange))
                x+=xchange;
            else
                y+=ychange;
        }
    }
}

void Entity::obj_event(Player *player)
{
    collide_action(player);
}

void Entity::obj_event(Enemy *enemy)
{
    collide_action(enemy);
}
```

This is my derived class of Entity, Player:

player.h:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H_INCLUDED
#define PLAYER_H_INCLUDED
#include "all.h"
#include "body.h"
#include "items.h"
#include <vector>
#include "mask.h"
#include "entity.h"
enum keylist
{
    kl_left=0,
    kl_up=1,
    kl_right=2,
    kl_down=3,
};

class Player : public Entity
{
public:
    SDLKey keys[4]; //List of action's corresponding keys.
    Player(int xx,int yy,int w,int h,int d=0,int p=0);
    void step();
    void draw(SDL_Surface *buffer,int viewx,int viewy);

    void interact(Body *body);
};

#endif // PLAYER_H_INCLUDED
```

player.cpp:

```
#include "player.h"
#include "room.h"

Player::Player(int xx,int yy,int ww,int hh,int dd,int pp):Entity(xx,yy,ww,hh,dd,pp)
{
    //Default keys, can be changed.
    keys[kl_left]=SDLK_LEFT;
    keys[kl_up]=SDLK_UP;
    keys[kl_right]=SDLK_RIGHT;
    keys[kl_down]=SDLK_DOWN;
}
void Player::step()
{
    Uint8 *key=SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
    if (key[keys[kl_left]])
        x-=1;
    if (key[keys[kl_right]])
        x+=1;
    if (key[keys[kl_up]])
        y-=1;
    if (key[keys[kl_down]])
        y+=1;
    mask.update(x,y,width,height);
    Entity::step();
}
void Player::draw(SDL_Surface *buffer,int viewx,int viewy)
{
    FillRect(buffer,x-viewx,y-viewy,width,height,0xFF0000);
}


void Player::interact(Body *body){body->obj_event(this);}
```

I have another class Enemy, but it's pretty much exactly like player (without the keyboard controls).

Now here's my problem (not error), for every object I want any body to perform an event for, I need to make virtual functions of ALL of them in this base class, that way if any object calls body->obj_event(this), it will pick the proper function with the most derived argument.

For example, if Player called object->interact(this) of an enemy, the enemy would first use it's base class **Object**'s virtual function interact(Body*), which would then check the derived classes if they have an identical function (which enemy does), and then enemy calls body->obj_event(this) of the player body through it's base class, **Body**. The player body would then first use it's base class **Body**'s virtual function obj_event(Enemy*), which would then check the derived classes if they have an identical function (which Entity does), and then Entity executes obj_event(Enemy*). At least that's how I understand it.

What I'd like to have is a way for any derived class to call interact of any other derived class through it's base function, and would then have it call it's obj_event function for the derived class, without having to have any of the Base classes know about their derived classes.

As I mentioned, this is my first time making an engine, and I'm probably using methods that are completely hectic and error-prone. I was thinking that templates might be able to help out in this situation, but don't know how to implement them.

Comment: What you're trying to do is really, really generic. How is any one class to know how it will "interact" with another class? There is no context passed between objects?

Comment: @Aesthete I'm not sure what you're asking, but the idea was for any body to get the type of class another object is, and perform an event accordingly. I didn't want the called object to perform any actions with the calling object, so there was no need to send any 'context', if that's what you were asking.